# Clarification about standard html5 tag

Tags: html

For best practices, i have to creating web pages using some templates from online.

In main content, for the slideshow,below code i am using:

```
<main class = "content">
<div id = "slideshow">
<img src = "img/slide-1.jpg" alt = "" />
<img src = "img/slide-2.jpg" alt = "" />
<img src = "img/slide-1.jpg" alt = "" />
<img src = "img/slide-2.jpg" alt = "" />
<img src = "img/slide-1.jpg" alt = "" />
</div>
</main>
```

In templates below the slideshow, it shows like this,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/zrJd1.jpg

after that like this,

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nrg4z.jpg

I know there lot of ways to do it with html5.

But i need to know, what are the standard format of html5 tags using to these parts.

May i know how to do this, sorry for this trivial question. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your question. What do you try to achieve. Why does this fail?

Comment: This is not fail.. i am confused with using exact standard html5 tags.

Comment: Which tags are you confused about?

Comment: according to my first posted image..http://imgur.com/p6S1dub i confused, with these tags.. article,aside,blockquote..

Comment: This can not be seen on your screenshot. Please ask a clear question!

Comment: my side, it looks clearly.

Answer (score 0):

For the slideshow, as this is the main content of your page, wrap it with `<main>`. Each img tag should be wrapped with `<figure>`, and if you're providing a caption, `<figcaption>`.

```
<div>
   <img src="…" />
   <img src="…" />
</div>
```

becomes…

```
<main>
  <div>
    <figure>
      <img src="…" />
    </figure>
    <figure>
      <img src="…" />
    </figure>
  </div>
</main>
```

For the sub-content, this depends entirely on what content you put there. If you put a summary of the content shown in the gallery, then wrap it with `<summary>`. If its supplementary content, use `<aside>`. Either way, this should be wrapped with `<section>`.

The testimonials should be wrapped with `<aside>`.

Again with the secondary sub-content, it depends what you are showing here. If it's part of every page, use `<footer>`. If it's simply more supplementary content, use `<aside>` with `<section>`.